# post data to localhost in android app

Tags: php, android, localhost

I am new to android and am trying to post data to localhost from my android app. While it is not showing any errors, and always say command sent, it is not writing the file or perhaps it is not posting any data. Can anyone spot the problem, or tell me how can I fix it?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.register;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText value;
private Button btn;
private ProgressBar pb;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){
// out of range
Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());  
}

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
postData(params[0]);
return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/text.php");

try {
// Add your data
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:text="Enter Something Below:"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint=""
>

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: print response string ? what are u getting there?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `10.0.2.2` IP address to connect with localhost system.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/text.php");
```

Should be

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/text.php");
```

Comment: i have use this but still it is not posting , actually i am new to android and can you tell me where can i check whats the issue , because right now it is not showing ant error onclick , just show command send

Comment: @RohitGoel Check the response you get in `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i print the response

Answer (score 3):

1. Use IP address instead of localhost. Example:

   ```
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.10/mypage.php");
   ```
2. Add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` Example :

Comment: In which way is `192.168.0.10` localhost?

Comment: @MdKamruzzaman: you could not be farer from the truth. First of all, it is a question of the binding address of MongoDB. Second, while all other IPs of a machine may change, localhost or 127.0.0.1 never changes because they are defined that way.