# how to print response in android app

Tags: android, localhost, printf, response

Hi I am new to android and i am trying to post data to localhost but i am not getting any response or error

```
public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/text.php");

try {
// Add your data
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

please suggest me how can i print the response so that i can come to know where is the issue

Comment: What  your are trying to do ? connect to mysql via php?

Comment: thus is what i am trying to do 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962183/post-data-to-localhost-in-android-app/17962220?noredirect=1#comment26254256_17962220

Answer (score 0):

From your response:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
  if (statusCode == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      builder.append(line);
    }
  }
```